# Нужна ли запятая после слова "хочешь"

Tags: пунктуация

Рассматриваются 3 пункта:

1. Хочешь, я приеду к тебе.
2. Хочешь торт со сливками.
3. Хочешь его книгу, мы уезжаем завтра.

В 1-ом и во 2-ом пункте предполагается "хочешь" что-то. "я приеду к тебе" - это по сути что-то и можно назвать одним словом, например, "дело". По смыслу 1-ый и 2-ой пункт отличаются от 3-его пункта, т.к. в нем хочешь относится к "книге" а не к "мы уезжаем завтра".

Вопросы:
 1. Правильно ли расставлены запятые и почему так?
 2. Почему нужно ставить запятую в 1-ом пункте? Ведь "хочешь" относится к "я приеду к тебе", а не к чему то другому. По смыслу не образуется 2-х разных предложений в составе одного сложного в 1-ом пункте: "хочешь" и "я приеду к тебе".

Answer (score 2):

1) ***"Хочешь — я приеду к тебе".*** Я считаю, что  здесь надо тире, так как первая часть предложения выражает условие (можно поставить *"если"*). Если в конце предложения поставить вопросительный знак, то между частями можно поставить запятую.       
2) ***"Хочешь торт со сливками?"*** Здесь действительно нужен вопросительный знак. *"Хочешь (что?) торт"*, *"торт"* — дополнение, зависящее от сказуемого *"хочешь"*. *"Со сливками"* — это определение, если, конечно, *"торт со сливками"* — это не цельное название блюда.
3) ***"Хочешь его книгу, мы уезжаем завтра".*** Здесь, как заметил [[@behemothus](/users/445/behemothus)](/users/445/behemothus), довольно непонятная ситуация, без контекста не разобраться. Возможно, это два обычных предложения, соединенные бессоюзной связью. Если так, то запятая вполне правомерна.

Comment: 1) - согласен.

Answer (score 1):

~1. Хочешь, я приеду к тебе.   
Правильно
//---- уточнение.
Если воспринимать это как "если хочешь, то приеду", то тире. Согласен с Валентином.   Спасибо.
Я почему-то сначала воспринял это в еще менее естесвенном смысле "так как ты хочешь, то приеду".

~2. Хочешь торт со сливками? 
Нужен вопросительный знак. Без него фраза выглядит совершенно неестественной и синтаксис непрозначным.

~3. Хочешь его книгу, мы уезжаем завтра.
Без контекста никак не воспринимается с точки зрения логики, поэтому и комментировать нечего. Но вообще-то тут две очевидные основы, так что запятая все равно нужна, что юбы там автор не имел в виду.

> Почему нужно ставить запятую в 1-ом пункте? Ведь "хочешь" относится к "я приеду к тебе", а не к чему то другому.

А как этот факт сказывается на грамматике или синтаксисе?

> По смыслу не образуется 2-х разных предложений в составе одного сложного в 1-ом пункте: "хочешь" и "я приеду к тебе".

Отнюдь. Вполне себе образуется. Именно два простых в составе сложного. Если так понятнее, то разные производители действия "ты хочешь", "я приеду".

Comment: Образец научного комментария! Жирный плюс!

Comment: По-моему, если в первом предложении не ставить вопросительный знак, то надо тире, так как можно подставить "если..., то..." Разве не так?

Comment: >По-моему, если в первом предложении... 
Да. Согласен. Сообразил. Этот вараиант мне почему-то в голову не приходил. Но все равно как-то неестественно без контекста.