# Пунктуация в вопросе со словом "хочешь" и в сложноподчиненном с "и" как следствие

Tags: пунктуация

можете, пожалуйста, подсказать пунктуацию в предложениях: 
"Хочешь я буду твоим другом?"
"А потом воспользуюсь случаем и признаюсь в грехах!"

Answer (score 1):

1) ***Хочешь, я буду твоим другом?***

Это бессоюзное сложное предложение (БСП), ставится запятая.

Сравнить: Если хочешь, то я буду твоим другом. Это сложноподчиненное предложение (СПП) с тем же содержанием.

Обычно в БСП с условным значением ставится тире, но в простых по структуре предложениях возможна постановка запятой (пауза отсутствует).

Розенталь: Примечания: 1. Если значение следствия интонационно не подчеркивается, то вместо тире между частями бессоюзного сложного предложения ставится запятая: 
http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=151#pp151

Пример: А хочешь, погуляем под дождем? (Современная поэзия).

Тире в БСП ставится в следующем примере при наличии паузы: *Хочешь — погуляем, а хочешь — пойдем в кино.*

Эта тема обсуждалась на форуме:[Нужна ли запятая после слова "хочешь"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/13064/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%88%D1%8C)

2) ***А потом воспользуюсь случаем и признаюсь в грехах!***

Предложение односоставное, определенно-личное. Запятая не ставится между однородными сказуемыми при наличии одиночного союза И.